# Can i change default super class set by compiler in java?

Tags: java

every java class has root class is Object class. can i change that class and place of my own class `class MyObject extends Object`. it have some more functionally.

this thing is possible ???

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do it? it's not possible, and if you want to do it you probably want to do something that can be implemented in better (and right) way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. It's not even a compiler issue. `java.lang.Object` as the root of the inheritance hierarchy is a very fundamental fact of the language definition and even the VM specification.

Comment: but further after my Class will extends object... actually i want when we don't extend by default compiler will extends java.lang.Object right but i want change that to myPack.MyDefaultObject.. getting me or not?

Comment: @Ankur Patel: As I said, it's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible.  All objects in Java must derive from `java.lang.Object`.

If you want to add functionality to every object in your system, then I would just introduce your own `MyObject` class and make sure that all of your classes derive from this.  If you want to extend functionality to existing objects, then I'd use static helper methods to do this (in C# you'd use extension methods, but no such option exists in Java).

Comment: I wouldn't, but the guy that asked the question might!

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of anything like that. Why would you want to? It would make your code impossible to follow for anyone but you. Every Java programmer out there assumes that either you explicitly extend a class or you extend Object.

Is it really that much work to put in "extends MyObject" at the beginning of your classes? I am pretty sure that Eclipse (and other IDEs) can be configured to automatically insert it for you.

Comment: These days I'm pretty sure you could do it with AOP if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Beside that this seems a questionable approach to me -
you can use [bytecode instrumentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#bci) to archive this 
(but this is not done at compile-time but at vminit/classload time - depending on the type of instrumentation used).